# jQuery trigger click (vs human click) only partially working

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have a webpage where I want an action to happen either when the user clicks on a link, OR when the page loads IF the url contains a certain hash.

Here is the code that will be triggered when a human clicks on one of the links:

```
jQuery( ".mygroup a" ).click(function(e) {
// all the stuff that happens, including reference to and manipulation of extshapeAr
});
```

If the user clicks directly on any of the links, all of the dependant actions (changing font size and color, and changing colors on shapes on a separately loaded object on the rest of the page) work as expected.

But if I check the hash and if it is present use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var hashclean = hash.substr(1);
    if (hash) {
    jQuery('.mygroup a.'+ hashclean).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

The click is triggered and SOME of the code is executed, but then stops with a reference error telling me my separately loaded object is not defined.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: extshapeAr is not defined

shouldn't the trigger work the same way a human click would? What am I missing?

Comment: Please paste all your code with error function.

Comment: I understand, but there is a LOT of code and I wanted to keep the question as simple as possible. Maybe I need to reformulate the question, I will look at it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what was causing this. The code that created extshapeAr was taking too long to run, so even though I thought I was protected from that with my document ready declaration, apparently not. I had to place my hash check in the separately loaded code just after that object was created. Now it all works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You attach click handler to `jQuery( ".mygroup a" )` and somehow you triggered click event on `jQuery('.mygroup a.'+ hashclean)` which is not matched with first context. Ever changing it to match with the `jQuery( ".mygroup a" )`

Cant reproduce the error, can you replicate it, and paste it in here